# I want register new app in Soundcloud but it says Register new app (Currently unavailable)

Tags: ios

I want to integrate SoundCloud API in my iOS app, so i need SoundCloud Client id. But SoundCloud Developer Console does not provide to me register new app for my client id.

Anyone help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: At the moment, this isn't possible due official ways. 
It doesn't matter that you are from India.

Comment: Ok sir , how long it will be available.

Comment: idk, write them, probably they will answer you this question.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm quite sure they won't reopen the client id request due to music licences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the website it shows that the Register new app service is currently unavailable.

[image]